# Implementing RunAsync() correctly

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm working on a code that regularly screenshots a web page for an image, scans the pixel colors of the image, and if a color is found, connects asynchronously to a web API.

I have worked out how to do the color scanning and the connection separately and now I have to join the two logics but I'm not sure of the best way to do it .

The scanning web page/image scan code is essentially this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //refresh speed

                string color = ReadColor(driver, webElement);  

                if (color== "blue")
                {
                    //should connect for blue case and run the Blue() function below
                }
                if (color== "green")
                {
                     //should connect for green case
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }        
    }
```

the HttpClient connection goes like this:

```
 static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 static void Main()
 {
            RunAsync().Wait();
 }

  static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("website");

          Data data = new Data { };

        try
        {

             data = await Green();
             data = await blue();  //functions to run depending on color
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

how should the RunAsync().Wait(); method be properly inserted in the first example and how should I call the correct function?

EDIT:

ok so eventually I'm doing it this way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                string signal = ReadGraph(driver, webElement);  //////READ CHART

                if (signal == "blue")
                {
                    Task.Run(async () => await RunAsync(signal)).Wait();
                }

                if (signal == "green")
                {
                     RunAsync(signal);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }        
    }
```

however, whenever the RunAsync is called, it executes but the thread never returns to the main loop. 
I tried

```
Task.Run(async () => await RunAsync(signal)).Wait()
Task.Run(async () => await RunAsync(signal)).Wait()
RunAsync(signal);
RunAsync(signal).wait();
```

with the same result, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Calling `RunAsync().Wait()` is such a waste. Why not just have a `Run` method if you're un-asynching an async?

Comment: thanks @Enigmativity I've posted an update with my attempts as I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: Don't use `.Wait()`. If you do it is pointless using `async`.

Comment: Calling `Task.Run(async () => await RunAsync(signal)).Wait()` is like doing 3 nested `async` calls but then trashing all that and waiting for the results. You might as well just have a single method called `Run` and not do `async`.

Comment: oh right I got it now, I basically just made a `static void Run()` and simply calling that seems to work ok. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it if you want `async`:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
        string signal = ReadGraph(driver, webElement);
        if (signal == "blue")
        {
            await RunAsync(signal);
        }
        if (signal == "green")
        {
            await RunAsync(signal);
        }
    }
}
```